# Riddle: Dead or alive

Tags: riddle

> Forward, I will lead the way.
>   Backward, freedom you shall have.
>   Keep going, I'll hold them back.
>   Take my sword, do what you must.
>   Dead or alive, our rights are just.

**Who/what am I?**

> There!!! I just showed myself

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Inspired by Karm's answer, I think you are a

> Slash

Forward, I will lead the way.

> Forward slash (/) is the path component separator in a hierarchical directory structure.

Backward, freedom you shall have. (solved by Karm)

> Backslash (\) - escape character in many programming languages.

Keep going, I'll hold them back.

> The slash (as a "virgule") offset by spaces to either side is used to mark line breaks when transcribing text from a multi-line format into a single-line one. It holds back the lines.

Take my sword, do what you must.

> A slash is a wide, sweeping stroke made with a knife or sword.

Dead or alive, our rights are just.

> Not sure - possibly used to right-justify text in some scenarios.

There!!! I just showed myself

> In between "who" and "what" in the question.

Comment: +1 Nice Answer, think you have it

Comment: well, done. The final line I was emphasizing on **"or"**,
& well on the third line, I want to point out they are separating

Answer (score 3):

Is the answer:

> Punctuation

Forward, I will lead the way.

> Capital Letter - Starts any sentence

Backward, freedom you shall have.

> BackSlash - Escape character in many programming languages

Keep going, I'll hold them back.

> Full Stop - End of a declaratory, stopping the reader

Take my sword, do what you must.

> Dagger - Usually indicates a footnote (Not sure the second part)

Dead or alive, our rights are just.

> Not sure

There!!! I just showed myself

> Exclamation Marks hinting at the answer of Punctuation

Comment: Well I don't know how but you landed so close to the answer with 1 hint correct.